# Android Proximity alert doesn't get fired

Tags: android, gps, alert, proximity

this is my very first question:

I'm trying to configure proximity alerts that will be feed from a Database and webservice provider; but I have a problem configuring a simple proximity alert for testing. I manage to create the alert but it never gets fired, I'm only trying in the emulator for now and don´t know if I need some extra code to trigger the alerts.

I've read somewhere that the GPS provider to disabled so the network provider can be used in order to trigger the alerts on the emulator.

My code looks like this:

Proximity intent declaration

```
private String proximityIntentAction = new String("gpsdelivery.gpship.getLocation.GPS_PROXIMITY_ALERT");
```

Inside onStart() where the parameters of the alerts are set

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(proximityIntentAction);
registerReceiver(new ProximityAlert(), intentFilter);
setProximityAlert(45.150344, 9.999815, -1);
```

Proximity alert function where the alerts get created

```
private void setProximityAlert(double lat, double lon, int requestCode)
{
    // 100 meter radius
    float radius = 100f;
    // Expiration is 10 Minutes
    long expiration = 600000;
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(proximityIntentAction);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    locManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);

}
```

And finally my proximity alert class with the Broadcast receiver

```
public class ProximityAlert extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            Log.v("SomeTag","Proximity alert received");

        }

    }
```

Please let me know what I'm missing or what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance, any source code would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you assume you should be broadcasting a proximity alert? Have you set a location in the emulator in DDMS?

Comment: I thought the broadcast receiver was need it to perform the action want it after a proximity alert was triggered, at least that's how i saw it in other examples. I did set multiple locations inside the proximity radius in DDMS but the alert never gets fired, i got this error message: 10-07 01:22:50.681: ERROR/ActivityThread(796): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity gpsdelivery.gpship.getLocation has leaked IntentReceiver gpsdelivery.gpship.getLocation$ProximityAlert@43762ee8 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe your `setProximityAlert(45.150344, 9.999815, -1);` is incorrect.  Specifically, your -1.  It doesn't contain the information needed in the `locManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lon, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);`.